# Nested Cogrouped RDD printing: <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at ...>

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having some issues with printing/saving the RDD. Here is the sample code:

```
users_prods_joined = users_grpd.cogroup(prods_grpd) 

users_prods_joined_flattened = users_prods_joined.map(
   lambda (k, mapped): "{0} {1}".format(k,str(mapped)))

users_prods_joined_flattened.saveAsTextFile('users_prods_joined_flattened')
```

The o/p is :

```
cat users_prods_joined_flattened/part-00* | more
```

> 648018220 pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107cc5b50
>
> 100341214 pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107cc5b50
>
> 8429212  pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107cc5b50

......

I would like to know how to get the actual values rather than `pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107cc5b50 .....`

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
[(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(x.cogroup(y).collect()))]
```

Example:

```
>>> x = sc.parallelize([("foo", 1), ("bar", 4)])
>>> y = sc.parallelize([("foo", -1)])
>>> z = [(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(x.cogroup(y).collect()))]
>>> print(z)
```

You should get the desired output...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of cogroup at https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html you can see it returns RDD[(K, (Iterable[V], Iterable[W]))] where Iterable[V] and Iterable[W] contain values from the two separete RDDs. You'll have to iterate over them or turn them into a list by calling list(...) on them.

I assume something like this would work (note: code not tested):

```
users_prods_joined.map(lambda (k, mapped): "{0} {1}".format(k,str(list(mapped[0]) + list(mapped[1]))))
```

Comment: 00604220 [<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x1093cd890>, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x1093c64d0>]

5007820 [<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x1093c6410>, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x1093c6c50>]

Comment: It seems you have iterable objects from some other operations contained in the iterables. We can't really help you more since we don't see the rest of the code. Either way, the bottom line is that you have to handle the iterable objects somehow, either by turning them into lists or some other way, and this goes for the iterable objects you get from the cogroup operation and the iterable objects you get from previous operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `collect()` yet but still want to expand your iteretables you can do the following, using Harsha's example:

```
>>> x = sc.parallelize([("foo", 1), ("bar", 4)])
>>> y = sc.parallelize([("foo", -1)])
>>> grp = x.cogroup(y).mapValues(lambda val: [i for e in val for i in e])
```

A bit ugly, yet in one line you get one single list of all the grouped values instead of an Iterable